# How to convert binary pivot table to list view

Tags: r, vba

Trying to convert data from a pivot table to a list view for metrics purposes.

We receive data in binary (0 or 1) matrix format:

| **Item** | **North** | **East** | **South** | **West** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Oranges | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Bananas | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

But need to convert it to a list view:

| **Item** | **Store** |
| --- | --- |
| Apples | North |
| Apples | South |
| Oranges | East |
| Oranges | South |
| Bananas | East |
| Bananas | South |
| Bananas | West |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would help if you would edit your question to give some indication of what you have tried so far, as well as an indication of where in the code you seem to be having issues.

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, an option would be to `gather` the data into 'long' format, `filter` the rows where 'val' is 1 and remove the 'val' column

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   gather(Store, val, -Item, -rn) %>%
   filter(val == 1) %>%       
   arrange(rn) %>%
   select(-val, -rn)
#     Item Store
#1  Apples North
#2  Apples South
#3 Oranges  East
#4 Oranges South
#5 Bananas  East
#6 Bananas South
#7 Bananas  West
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Item = c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"), North = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), East = c(0L, 1L, 1L), South = c(1L, 1L, 1L), West = c(0L, 
0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```